# How to test a nested resource's controller with Rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec2

My nested resource are associated in the models and the routes.rb:

```
resources :foos do
  resources :bars
end
```

My app is routing ok, but I can't seem to prove any assertions about my nested routes:

```
describe BarsController do

it "should have a route to 'show'" do
  assert_generates "/foos/bars/1", 
                   {controller: :bars, action: :show, id: "1"}
end
```

Here is the error:

```
Failure/Error: assert_generates "/foos/bars/1",
ActionController::RoutingError:
No route matches {:controller=>"bars", :action=>"show", :id=>"1"}
```

How do I test these nested routes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run `rake routes` you should see that your nested routes look something like this:

```
foo_bar GET    /foos/:foo_id/bars/:id(.:format)      bars#show
```

So two parameters are required to match this route: `foo_id` and `id`. Since you're only supplying the `id`, it's failing to find a route.

Also, for testing routes in rspec, you may find it more useful to use the built-in `routes_to` matcher instead of falling back to `assert_*`, like this:

```
it "routes to the 'show' action" do
  { get: "/foos/123/bars/456" }.
    should route_to controller: "bars",
      action: "show",
      foo_id: "123",
      id: "456"
end
```

Comment: I see that someone has voted down this answer but left no comment to say why. Maybe it's because the rspec syntax has changed since February 2012 when this answer was written, but who can say?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `assert_generates`, `assert_recognizes` and `assert_routing` for [testing routes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#inspecting-and-testing-routes). For example,

```
assert_generates "/foo/bar/1", 
     { :controller => "bar", :action => "show", :id => "1" }
```

Comment: Thanks, nkm, for the useful trick. But I still can't seem to make that assertion true for a nested route. Edited above.

Comment: In above code, `{controller: :bars, action: :show, id: "1"}` seems like javascript way, in ruby it is `{controller => :bars, action => :show, id => "1"}`. But from the error message says no matching routes. Please confirm that corresponding route has been defined using `rake routes` command.

Comment: @nkm what you're calling the "javascript way" could also be called the Ruby 1.9 way. These are equivalent: `{ :one => 123 }` and `{ one: 123 }`

Comment: You are right @Rob Davis, I was not aware of that. Thanks for the update(+1) :)